# In C# Generics are these two lines of code identical?

Tags: c#, .net, oop

While reading about generics I came across those two chunks of code, and I was wondering if they were identical?

```
public abstract class Search<T, TCollection, TCriteria>
        where TCollection : Collection<Name>
        where T : Name
```

AND:

```
public abstract class Search<Name, Collection<Name>, TCriteria>
```

Comment: The second doesn't look like valid code to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Lasse pointed out, your second version doesn't compile. If you changed it to

```
public abstract class Search<Name, Collection, TCriteria>
```

it would compile, but it wouldn't do what you wanted it to do: This just specifies a generic class with three type parameters called `Name`, `Collection` and `TCriteria`. But it doesn't limit them in any way, so you could create an instance like `Search<int, long, ulong>`.

Type parameters usually start with `T`, but the language doesn't enforce it in any way.

So the difference is that the second version doesn't work, use the first one.

Answer (score 5):

No, because in the second you are specifying a concrete generic parameter but in the first you are specifying that the generic parameter can be any subclass of the type specified in the where clause.

Comment: Additionally, that second declaration is illegal due to the misuse of `Collectio<Name>`.